# File time structure in VC++

Tags: c++, winapi

```
typedef struct _FILETIME {
  DWORD dwLowDateTime;
  DWORD dwHighDateTime;
} FILETIME, *PFILETIME;
```

What part of time is stored in low date time and high data time? and how it will be stored in computer and how it will be displayed in 64 bit integer.

For example if I have `2012-06-18 09:45:03.180`.

I have to substract two file times so I am converting to int64 and subsracting, is this right way do it?

Comment: Just as an additional to the answers (which just beat me too it!), there is also this MSDN artical which provides a higher level overview to file times used by the Win API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Default makes a good point, usually MSDN has actually fairly decent documentation for the Win APIs, if you ever need to find information about an API your using, do a quick search for '[Struct/Class/API name] + MSDN'. :)

Answer (score 1):

Taken together `dwHighDateTime` and `dwLowDateTime` form a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond units since 12:00AM UTC on 1-Jan-1601.

You should never read or write the values in a FILETIME structure directly. You should use functions such as [FileTimeToSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the like to access the values in them.

Answer (score 0):

The structure is well documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Excerpt:

> The FILETIME structure is a 64-bit value representing the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

The two DWORDS are used to define the structure as you should not make calculation with it by yourself. Please see the **Remarks** section in the referenced MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

[FILETIME structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

For an example see [SystemTimeToFileTime function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4), `FILETIME` is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). So in your example, which is approximately 150183 days, 9 hours, 45 minutes, 3 seconds and 180 thousands, they should be about:

- 0x779C70C0 (low)
- 0x01CCFEA2 (high)

**Edit:** converting to `__int64` and subtracting, just as you say, works well.

Comment: Can you please explain how do you got 0x779C70C0  number?

Comment: Use [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @venkysmarty: `((((150183*24+9)*60+45)*60+3)*1000+180)*1000*10 = 129758463031800000 = 0x1CCFEA2779C70C0`. Lowest 32 bits is that number.